# Why is Perl's IO::Socket::SSL->new() failing?

Tags: perl, ssl, sockets

When I execute this line:

```
$client = IO::Socket::SSL->new("pilot-payflopro.paypal.com:443");
```

my `IO::Socket::SSL::errstr()` is

```
configuration error
failederror:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
```

my `$!` is 'invalid argument'

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a gethostbyname failure: the domain "pilot-payflopro.paypal.com" doesn't exist. You need a working hostname like payflow.verisign.com or what not. Read the documentation again.

Comment: I wrote the wrong url in there, the domain actually did exist; it turns out that the hostname service was down on our VM using this code (which would have caused the same problem), thanks.